# Why can't I retrieve the row of an input field in a jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to create a datatable, and respond to user input in it. When I get a change event on an input field in the table, I want to find out which row the event is in.
As I understand it, `table.api().row(item)` should return the row object containing the item. But it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//datatables.net/download/build/nightly/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script>
function drawInput(data, type, row, meta) {
    return '<input id="r' + meta.row + 'c' + meta.col + '" val="' + data + '"></input>';
}
var data = [ { c1: 'r1c1', c2: 'r1c2' }, { c1: 'r2c1', c2: 'r2c2' }];
$(function() {
    var table = $('table').dataTable({
        info: false,
        searching: false,
        ordering: false,
        paging: false,
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'c1',
                name: 'c1',
                heading: 'Col 1',
                defaultContent: '<input></input>',
                render: drawInput
            },
            {
                data: 'c2',
                name: 'c2',
                heading: 'Col 2',
                defaultContent: '<input></input>',
                render: drawInput
            }
        ]
    });
    table.api().rows.add(data);
    table.api().draw();
    $('body').on('change', 'table :input', function(e) {
        // Find the row that contains the input field
        console.log(this);
        var row = table.api().row(this);
        // Show the row index - result is undefined! Why?
        console.log(row.index());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <table width="100%">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
 </table>
</body>
</html>
```

P.S. I'm sure I used to be able to make code snippets executable on Stack Overflow. But I've forgotten how?

Comment: [I've been told to create a "runnable" example with "Stack Snippets". How do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1427878)

Comment: It doesn't take the input field as a valid selector to determine the row, the vaid options are listed under https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your issue.

Your not using the API correctly.

https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell().index()
https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().index()

```js
function drawInput(data, type, row, meta) {
  return '<input id="r' + meta.row + 'c' + meta.col + '" val="' + data + '"></input>';
}

$(function() {
  var data = [{
    c1: 'r1c1',
    c2: 'r1c2'
  }, {
    c1: 'r2c1',
    c2: 'r2c2'
  }];
  var table = $('table').dataTable({
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    columns: [{
        data: 'c1',
        name: 'c1',
        heading: 'Col 1',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c2',
        name: 'c2',
        heading: 'Col 2',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      }
    ]
  });
  table.api().rows.add(data);
  table.api().draw();
  $('body').on('change', 'tbody td', function(e) {
    console.log(table.api().cell(this).index());
    console.log(table.api().row(this).index());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table width="100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thankyou - serves me right for trying to understand the source, instead of looking at the docs properly. I have used `var row = table.api().row($(this).closest('td'));` on the original input, which works fine.

Comment: Unfortunately this no longer works if the table is responsive. See this related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76858790/responsive-jquery-datatables-cant-find-row-index-from-cell-in-child