# Responsive jquery datatables can't find row index from cell in child

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a datatable with input fields. When a user inputs to a field, I need to find the row number they have input to. I asked a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76857261/why-cant-i-retrieve-the-row-of-an-input-field-in-a-jquery-datatable), and got a good answer, but the answer stops working if the datatable is responsive, and the field is in the child popdown.
Here is my code:

```js
function drawInput(data, type, row, meta) {
  return '<input id="r' + meta.row + 'c' + meta.col + '" val="' + data + '"></input>';
}
var data = [{
  c1: 'r1c1',
  c2: 'r1c2',
  c3: 'r1c3'
}, {
  c1: 'r2c1',
  c2: 'r2c2',
  c3: 'r2c3'
}];
$(function() {
  var table = $('table').dataTable({
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    columns: [{
        defaultContent: '<span></span>'
      },
      {
        data: 'c1',
        name: 'c1',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c2',
        name: 'c2',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c3',
        name: 'c3',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      }
    ]
  });
  table.api().rows.add(data);
  table.api().draw();
  $('body').on('change', 'table :input', function(e) {
    // Find the row that contains the input field
    //console.log(this);
    var row = table.api().row($(this).closest('td'));
    // Show the row index - result is undefined! Why?
    console.log(row.index());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<div style='width:150px;'>
<table width="100%" class="responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

If you run this in a window large enough to fit the whole table in, it works fine. But if you narrow the window down, so that the right hand column responsively drops into a child row, the code to find the row index no longer works.

What is the correct incantation to find row for a child cell?

Answer (score 0):

When `.row($(this).closest("td")).index()` is undefined, use `table.api().row(this).index()`.

Strangely, `table.api().row(this)` only works on the expanded row, not the original, so need to continue to use .closest("td") for the original row.

Specifically `table.api().row(...)` will return a jQuery object, so to check if any rows have been returned, check for `.length === 0`.

Giving:

```
let row = table.api().row($(this).closest("td"))
if (row.length === 0) row = table.api().row(this);
```

then `.index()` will give the expected row index.

Updated snippet:

```js
function drawInput(data, type, row, meta) {
  return '<input id="r' + meta.row + 'c' + meta.col + '" val="' + data + '"></input>';
}
var data = [{
  c1: 'r1c1',
  c2: 'r1c2',
  c3: 'r1c3'
}, {
  c1: 'r2c1',
  c2: 'r2c2',
  c3: 'r2c3'
}];
$(function() {
  var table = $('table').dataTable({
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    columns: [{
        defaultContent: '<span></span>'
      },
      {
        data: 'c1',
        name: 'c1',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c2',
        name: 'c2',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c3',
        name: 'c3',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      }
    ]
  });
  table.api().rows.add(data);
  table.api().draw();
  $('body').on('change', 'table :input', function(e) {
    // Find the row that contains the input field
    console.log(this.id, this.name, table.api().row($(this).closest("td")).index(), table.api().row(this).index());
    
    var row = table.api().row($(this).closest("td"))
    if (row.length === 0) row = table.api().row(this);
    // Show the row index - result is undefined! Why?
    console.log(row.index());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<div style='width:150px;'>
<table width="100%" class="responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector#Options says about passing a node as row selector,

> tr - table row element.
> td - table cell element (Since: 1.10.11).
> Any element which has a data-dt-row attribute assigned to it, or a parent (Since: 1.10.11). This can be used by extensions such as FixedColumns and Responsive to allow easy row selection.

If you check the actual DOM, it looks like this:

[image]

So there is an element with a `data-dt-row` attribute, only it is not a `td`, it's a `li`.

So you need to find either that closest element with that data attribute, or if that does not exist, pick the closest `td` instead.

```js
function drawInput(data, type, row, meta) {
  return '<input id="r' + meta.row + 'c' + meta.col + '" val="' + data + '"></input>';
}
var data = [{
  c1: 'r1c1',
  c2: 'r1c2',
  c3: 'r1c3'
}, {
  c1: 'r2c1',
  c2: 'r2c2',
  c3: 'r2c3'
}];
$(function() {
  var table = $('table').dataTable({
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    columns: [{
        defaultContent: '<span></span>'
      },
      {
        data: 'c1',
        name: 'c1',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c2',
        name: 'c2',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c3',
        name: 'c3',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      }
    ]
  });
  table.api().rows.add(data);
  table.api().draw();
  $('body').on('change', 'table :input', function(e) {
    // Find the row that contains the input field
    var row = table.api().row($(this).closest('[data-dt-row], td').get(0));
    // Show the row index - result is undefined! Why?
    console.log(row.index());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<div style='width:150px;'>
<table width="100%" class="responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
      <th>Col 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Again ;) Need to just specify how to access the Table Cell.

```js
function drawInput(data, type, row, meta) {
  return '<input id="r' + meta.row + 'c' + meta.col + '" val="' + data + '"></input>';
}
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    c1: 'r1c1',
    c2: 'r1c2',
    c3: 'r1c3'
  }, {
    c1: 'r2c1',
    c2: 'r2c2',
    c3: 'r2c3'
  }];
  var table = $('table').dataTable({
    info: false,
    searching: false,
    ordering: false,
    paging: false,
    columns: [{
        defaultContent: '<span></span>'
      },
      {
        data: 'c1',
        name: 'c1',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c2',
        name: 'c2',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      },
      {
        data: 'c3',
        name: 'c3',
        defaultContent: '<input></input>',
        render: drawInput
      }
    ]
  });
  table.api().rows.add(data);
  table.api().draw();
  $('body').on('change', 'tbody td input', function(e) {
    console.log(table.api().cell(this.parentNode).index());
    console.log(table.api().row(this.parentNode).index());
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.6/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.5.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<div style='width:150px;'>
  <table width="100%" class="responsive">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Col 1</th>
        <th>Col 2</th>
        <th>Col 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```